# Porting debian to leopord dm368

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am trying to port debian linux distribution on leopord dm36X.

Have anyone ported it already? If yes please provide pointers from where to start..

Comment: If you get the kernel up, some of the ARM Debian flavours may just work, just like that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that kernel is ported to [dm365](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/mach-davinci/dm365.c;h=b680c832e0ba87758f1f29aeb502109ce2699268;hb=b69f0859dc8e633c5d8c06845811588fe17e68b3), there is also BSP for leopard made [dm355](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/mach-davinci/board-dm355-leopard.c;h=2f88103c64595c1f68a3ad9f7ca026e0b8644741;hb=b69f0859dc8e633c5d8c06845811588fe17e68b3) based board and evaluation board for [dm365](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/mach-davinci/board-dm365-evm.c;h=1b4a8adcfdc9f1f86f87079c8ab8b009e0bc105a;hb=b69f0859dc8e633c5d8c06845811588fe17e68b3) from TI - these all might be relevant depending on how different dm368 is.

I guess this is the starting point, i would also check TI's developers discussion boards for any announcements.